# webbrowser delphi

Tags: delphi

Есть самая обычная форма на которой одна кнопка и webbrowser, при нажатии на кнопку попадаем в гугл.
//событие по клику кнопки
    webbrowser1.Navigate'https://google.com/';
//браузер дожидается полной загрузки

после чего я в браузере ввожу нужный мне сайт и совершаю по нему переход
//тут я присвоил событие onBeforce2... при котором создаётся  webbrowser2 и PageTab2 и открывает там сайт.
 смотрю на статистику вебвизора - Прямой заход.
 Что делаю не так?

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.OleCtrls, SHDocVw,
Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
TForm1 = class(TForm)
PageControl1: TPageControl;
TabSheet1: TTabSheet;
TabSheet2: TTabSheet;
WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
WebBrowser2: TWebBrowser;
Button1: TButton;
procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
procedure WebBrowser1NewWindow2(ASender: TObject; var ppDisp: IDispatch;
  var Cancel: WordBool);
private
{ Private declarations }
public
{ Public declarations }
end;

 var
Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
webbrowser1.navigate('https://www.google.ru/');
end;


procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1NewWindow2(ASender: TObject; var ppDisp: IDispatch;
 var Cancel: WordBool);

begin

ppDisp := Webbrowser2.DefaultDispatch;
 end;

 end.
```

Comment: а какое поведение вы ожидаете? Вопрос непонятен, нужно его уточнение/детализация. Ну и уточните заодно среду разработки и платформу (VCL / FMX)